# I am using spark version 2.1, I have a few of phone numbers and I need to assign same random number to the similar phone numbers, in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I am using scala.util.Random.Shuffle(phoneNumber.toList) to get the random numbers for all my phone numbers, but I have duplicate phone numbers in my list of phone numbers, I want to assign same random number to all the duplicate phone numbers.

I am already using denseRank() to get those duplicate values sorted out.

Comment: The Question is unclear. What is the issue you are facing? Are you unable to assign same random numbers to same values? Or is it something else?
Show the lines of code where you are trying to use the denseRank() logic.

Comment: Yes I am unable to get same random numbers for the duplicate phone numbers.

Comment: Val df = sqlContext.select(table).with column("rowNum",dense_rank().over(Window.orderBy("phone_number")))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this-

```scala
    val getRandom = udf((seed: Long) => new Random(seed).shuffle(seed.toString.toCharArray.iterator).mkString("").toLong)
    Seq(123456, 234567, 345678, 123456, 456789, 123456, 123456, 123456).toDF("phone_number")
      .withColumn("rand_number", getRandom($"phone_number"))
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +------------+-----------+
      * |phone_number|rand_number|
      * +------------+-----------+
      * |123456      |512634     |
      * |234567      |372456     |
      * |345678      |847635     |
      * |123456      |512634     |
      * |456789      |789546     |
      * |123456      |512634     |
      * |123456      |512634     |
      * |123456      |512634     |
      * +------------+-----------+
      */
```

> Please note the shuffle for duplicate phone number `123456` is always same. This can be considered as deterministic version of `shuffle` spark function

Comment: I need to random shuffle the phone numbers, so I am iterating through the numbers like. for(i <- 0 to df.length) { Val rnd = scala.util.random.shuffle(df(i).toList).mkString("")}

Comment: It works fine for all other cases but if the random value starts with 0 it removes that

Comment: remove last `toLong` then. `val getRandom = udf((seed: Long) => new Random(seed).shuffle(seed.toString.toCharArray.iterator).mkString(""))`

Comment: I encountered 1 more issue, here.. whenever I feed a number which starts with 0, such as 0076562865,0916838865. It ignores the 0s everytime. Since I need to skip the first 4 digits, so whenever I get leading 0s from 5th position of the number, it ignores them. Like : I am doing with column("new_Col",substring(col, 5, src_col.length)) and then I call the with column("phone",getRandom($"new_Col"))

Comment: input: 000542, output: 245

Comment: Can you tell me your input column type. If it is string, accept string in the udf and output string. So your udf should look like..`val getRandom = udf((seed: String) => new Random(seed).shuffle(seed.toCharArray.iterator).mkString(""))`

Comment: Input string is type char and String is giving error as "cannot resolve constructor"

Comment: please put whatever you have tried as update-1 in question description above